# How to get Selector Substitute Key / Description values

Tags: acumatica

Lets say I have a DAC record, like SOOrder, and I have a field like customerID, where there is a PXSelectorAttribute defined on an integer field, that has a SubstitueKey = typeof(Customer.acctCD) and Description = typeof(Customer.acctName). Is there some way that I can get the values of the substitute key / description field for that record without doing a PXSelect against the selectors table?

Thanks
-Kyle

Comment: Probably not what you're looking for, but you could do ``SOOrder.FK.Customer.FindParent(*graph*, soOrder)`` or ``Customer.PK.Find(*graph*, soOrder.CustomerID)``

Comment: Yeah, I am looking for something a little more abstract, thanks though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Note since no version was specified my example was coded against 2020r2*

The following is an example that updates an Invoice/Memo's Description to the Location's CD and Descr fields [CD: Descr] when the location is changed on the Invoice/Memo. I believe the function you're looking for is `PXSelectorAttribute.Select<SELECTOR_FIELD>(SELECTOR_FIELD_CACHE, SELECTOR_FIELD_RECORD) AS SELECTOR_TARGET_DAC`.

```
public class ArInvoiceEntrySoExt : PXGraphExtension<ARInvoiceEntry>
{
    #region Event Handlers
    #region ArInvoice
    public virtual void _(Events.FieldUpdated<ARInvoice.customerLocationID> e, PXFieldUpdated del)
    {
        var inv = e.Row as ARInvoice;
        del?.Invoke(e.Cache, e.Args);
        if (inv != default)
        {
            var loc = PXSelectorAttribute.Select<ARInvoice.customerLocationID>(e.Cache, inv) as Location;
            e.Cache.SetValueExt<ARInvoice.docDesc>(inv, string.Format("{0}: {1}", loc?.LocationCD, loc?.Descr));
        }
    }
    #endregion
    #endregion
}
```

An alternative, you can use `PXSelectorAttribute.GetField(SELECTOR_FIELD_CACHE, SELECTOR_FIELD_RECORD, "SELECTOR_FIELD_NAME", SELECTOR_FIELD_VALUE, "SELECTOR_TARGET_FIELD_NAME")` to get a specific field from the selector's target record. As an example, the following code does the same thing as above using this alternative method:

```
public class ArInvoiceEntrySoExt : PXGraphExtension<ARInvoiceEntry>
{
    #region Event Handlers
    #region ArInvoice
    public virtual void _(Events.FieldUpdated<ARInvoice.customerLocationID> e, PXFieldUpdated del)
    {
        var inv = e.Row as ARInvoice;
        del?.Invoke(e.Cache, e.Args);
        if (inv != default)
        {
            var loc = PXSelectorAttribute.Select<ARInvoice.customerLocationID>(e.Cache, inv) as Location;
            e.Cache.SetValueExt<ARInvoice.docDesc>(inv, string.Format("{0}: {1}",
                PXSelectorAttribute.GetField(e.Cache, inv, "customerLocationID", inv.CustomerLocationID, "LocationCD"),
                PXSelectorAttribute.GetField(e.Cache, inv, "customerLocationID", inv.CustomerLocationID, "Descr")));
        }
    }
    #endregion
    #endregion
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I also was told about another method that can be used

PXFieldState.UnwrapValue(object value) will return the UI equivalent of a value in the back end. This is nice because then you can use one method for both drop downs and selectors, but I cant seem to see how to get the description field using this